# Why is my player unable to move when touching the ground?

Tags: movement, game-maker, platformer

I want to make a little platformer. I watched [Shaun Spalding's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IysShLIaosk) but nothing seems to work. Everything was fine until I put in the collision detection. But the player can't move while he's on the ground.

Here's the code:

```
//Get the player's input
key_right = keyboard_check(vk_right);
key_left = - keyboard_check(vk_left);
key_jump = keyboard_check_pressed(vk_space);

//react to inputs
move = key_left + key_right;
hsp = move * movespeed;
if (vsp < 10) vsp += grav;

if (place_meeting(x,y+1,obj_wall))
{
    vsp = key_jump * -jumpspeed;
}

//horizontal collision
if (place_meeting(x+hsp,y,obj_wall))
{
    while(!place_meeting(x+sign(hsp),y,obj_wall))
    {
        x += sign(hsp);
    }
    hsp = 0;
}
x += hsp;

//Vertical collision
if(!place_meeting(x,y+sign(vsp),obj_wall))
{
    while(!place_meeting(x,y+sign(vsp),obj_wall))
    {
        y+=sign(vsp);
    }
    vsp=0;
}
y += vsp;
```

That's all in the step event for the player.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have

```
//Vertical collision
if(!place_meeting(x,y+sign(vsp),obj_wall))
{
    while(!place_meeting(x,y+sign(vsp),obj_wall))
    {
        y+=sign(vsp);
    }
    vsp=0;
}
y += vsp;
```

but I should have

```
//Vertical collision
if(!place_meeting(x,y+sign(vsp),obj_wall))
{
    while(!place_meeting(x,y+vsp,obj_wall))
    {
        y+=sign(vsp);
    }
    vsp=0;
}
y += vsp;
```